# Pass value from UserDefault to a string in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm getting a value in let variable , now i want to pass it to a string variable but when i try to pass it it shows error that Use of unresolved identifier . My code to get value is this,

```
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") {
    print("Found \(str)")
} else {
    print("No string for key")
}
```

and to whom i'm passing is this,

```
senderDisplayName = str
```

This is the senderDisplayName

```
- (void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button withMessageText:(NSString *)text senderId:(NSString *)senderId senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName date:(NSDate *)date { NSAssert(NO, @"Error! required method not implemented in subclass. Need to implement %s", PRETTY_FUNCTION); }
```

Comment: Where did you put the line `senderDisplayName = str`? Can you show what method are your two code snippets in?

Comment: I'm using JSQMessageViewConroller class the senderDisplayName is  coming from there. @Sweeper

Comment: @siddle declare a global variable of type string(ex-: senderDisplayName :String?) and then assign value inside if let(ex-: senderDisplayName = str) to this variable. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @siddle where is the code `senderDisplayName = str` written

Comment: This is the senderDisplayName  - (void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button
           withMessageText:(NSString *)text
                  senderId:(NSString *)senderId
         senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName
                      date:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error! required method not implemented in subclass. Need to implement %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

Comment: @siddle please update question , keep comment section clean, as it's difficult for anyone to understand like this.

Comment: @siddle where are you calling this method from? Post that code

Comment: I'm using JSQMessagesViewController as my subclass in ViewController for firebase chat , the senderDisplayName is coming from that class in which i have to pass the name if user which is login . @InderKumar

Comment: I have edited check it out. @TusharSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you code as:

```
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") {
     print("Found \(str)")
     senderDisplayName = str
else {
     print("No string for key")
}
```

or other code that you can write by using as **guard**:

```
guard let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") else {
   return
}
senderDisplayName = str
```

Comment: thanks a lot the second one is correct , big thanks. @Jacky